# Node.js Async for loop not running

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, for-of-loop

I'm working on setting up a for loop to add data to Redis. Since all Redis calls are asynchronous, and I can't just add in a JSON object, I'm trying to use a `for..of` loop to add everything. My issue is that it isn't running the loop for some reason. Here is the code:

```
    var idObj =  {"id": profileId}         
    if(){     
    // this code is working fine
    } else {
    console.log('made it to the else statement');
    async function AsyncForLoop() {
      for (var key of Object.keys(idObj)) {
        console.log('in the for loop');
        await hsetAsync(profileId, key, idObj[key]); 
      }
      AsyncForLoop();
      json.status = "ok";
      res.send(JSON.stringify(json));
    };
  }
```

I can get to the "made it to the else statement" console log, but it never actually runs the for loop. I've tried making it an async function and then calling that function, but it still isn't running. I'm not even getting a response from `res.send()` What am I missing here?

Comment: i mean... the forLoop function is never called.

Comment: I updated the original question. Even running it as a function and then calling it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to set up the for..of loop to just run asynchronously without having be in a function?

Comment: Calling the function from inside itself still never calls it in the first place so that it can call itself.

Comment: Yeah, I had my brackets wrong. Thanks for pointing that out